# Clear Cash in android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have android application, I use SQLite data base in my application, I have a question about data base in setting -> application manager if I select clear data or clear cash, our data base deletes, but I need data base. For example user remove data base suddenly after that my program does not work, my program is related to data base, how do I do, how can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to find some way to backup your database to the SD card. You could just dump it as a CSV-type file, which would exactly mimic the structure of a database, or else create some other kind of format which would work better for you. And then in the case that the database is cleared, you will need to parse the text file you created as the backup, and put it all back into the database.